# Vertical Spacing After Paragraph Heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

**I can't manage to control vertical spacing after (and before) paragraph which I've customized.**

\paragraph{Çatışma}
Birden fazla düşman birimin karşılıklı yok etme ....

And here is what i used to customize this:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage[overload]{textcase} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.ps}{pdf}{.pdf}{epstopdf er.ps --outfile \OutputFile}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\addto\extrasturkish{\uccode`i=\string"9D \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{\uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{#1}

\raggedbottom
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\Alph{paragraph}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection  {paragraph}
                                        {4}
                                        {\z@}%
                                        {0ex\@plus -0ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                        {0.0001pt \@plus .2ex}%
                                        {\itshape\normalsize}}

\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsubsection}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-10 pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\paragraph{0pt}{-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-10 pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}


\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}

\newcounter{subcount}





\begin{document}
```

[image: example]
I'm not even sure which packages effect each other and why... Any kind of help will be nice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you indicated with document class (article?, report? book? etc.) you use. Please consider augmenting the code you're provided so far into a compilable MWE (minimum working example). By the way, your two side-by-side examples are quite confusing: The one on the left has a `\paragraph`-style sectioning command whereas the one on the right has `\section` and `\subsection` headers but no `\paragraph` header. What exactly are we supposed to focus on?

Comment: For a MWE you should add the used \documentclass as well as some text to see/check for the intended behaviour.

Comment: Done. Because of the code size is too big i felt a bit of uncomfortable

Comment: @Mico there is too much space between text before and after heading. This is the main problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mix up standard LaTeX style for section heading definitions (via `\@startsection`) with the declarative method used by `titlesec`. And that doesn't work.

Remove the redefinition for `\paragraph`and instead use:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph} {\itshape\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{#1}
\titlespacing\paragraph{0pt}{-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-15 pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

and adjust the values for spacing as you wish.

Standard LaTeX method doesn't work if you have a `\parskip` that is big (eg `\baselineskip`) as in the `\@startsection` command the `\parskip`is always added to all dimensions. And if you try to go nevative to account for it it changes from display heading to inline heading ... a documented bug (aka feature)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I just changed ...{\theparagraph}{1em}{} to ...{\theparagraph}{1em}{#1} an it work perfect.

Comment: @interlude Yep, my mistake, sorry for that, or should I say exercise for the reader :-)  I fixed it in the answer.